# Declaring different types of variable dynamically

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way to specify the type of a variable dynamically. Something along the lines of:

```
public struct A
{
    int a, b;
}

public struct B
{
    double a, b;
}

public static int Main()
{
    var file = new StreamReader("input.txt");

    if(file.ReadLine() == "Struct A")
        var myVar = new A();
    else if(file.ReadLine() == "Struct B")
        var myVar = new B();
}
```

Such that I will specify what type of variable to declare depending on a input file.

Comment: You can define `myVar` as `object`. Or `dynamic`.

Comment: If that were possible, how do you intend to use the *myVar*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is rather silly. Perhaps it is just an example, but there is no point in reading the string twice from the file, just to do a comparison. Read the string once, storing it into a variable, and then do the comparison against the variable.

Also, you should be disposing your `StreamReader` object. Better yet, wrap its creation in a `using` block to ensure that it is automatically disposed.

As far as your actual problem, as has been suggested, you can declare the `myVar` variable with either an `object` or `dynamic` type.

When combined with the conditional operation, this will also solve your variable-scoping problem.

All together, something like the following:

```
public static int Main()
{
    dynamic myVar;
    using (var file = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
    {
        var line = file.ReadLine();
        if (line == "Struct A")
            myVar = new A();
        else if (line == "Struct B")
            myVar = new B();
        else
            // You really should be handling the case where the line in the file
            // contains neither "Struct A" or "Struct B". That will result in
            // myVar being left in an invalid, uninitialized state.
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    // do something with myVar, e.g.:
    return myVar.a;
}
```

Of course, this is not a silver bullet. It is going to be rather difficult to *use* `myVar` except in the simplest of cases, like the one you've shown in the question, where both `A` and `B` have a member `a`. The way that dynamic typing works is that the compiler waits to determine the variable's type until runtime. (As far as the CLR is concerned, a `dynamic` is just a variable of type `object`.) This means that you will not be able to use methods/properties/members of `A` when `myVar` is actually a `B`, and vice versa. You'll need some way of keeping track of what `myVar`'s actual type is. There are better ways of doing this, like implementing a common interface.